# MySQL allows subqueries without IN or comparison operator in WHERE clauses. How does it work?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, where-clause

**EDIT:** I wrongly simplified queries in the original version. this query was what I meant.

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.seq = B.seq
WHERE (select max(B.data) where B.data is not null group by B.seq);
```

[image]

I'll leave the wrong version since it also helped me about a scalar subquery.

---

My coworker asked why this statement works in MySQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM anytable
WHERE (SELECT 'asdf')
```

This returns 0 rows. I simplified the query, but basically, the where clause contains a subquery without IN or comparison operator; just itself. We expected it would throw an error about SQL syntax, just like SQL Server. But MySQL didn't.

Interestingly, If I change the query like below, the query returns all rows from `anytable`.

```
SELECT *
FROM anytable
WHERE (SELECT 1);
```

I couldn't find documentation about this. How does this work?

Comment: I assume 'asfd' results in false condition, but 1 results in true.

Comment: for me, this is a bug on mysql engine, where clause is suppose to have condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

When you do:

```
WHERE (SELECT 'asdf')
```

You have a scalar subquery.  This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE 'asdf'
```

Now, MySQL treats boolean values as integers and vice-versa, with `0` for false and anything else as true.  MySQL does not treat strings as booleans, so it decides to convert the value to a number, using implicit conversion.

The implicit conversion converts all leading digits.  There are none, so the value is converted to a `0`.  Voila!  It is treated as false.

When you use `WHERE (SELECT 1)` the same logic holds, except the value is already a number.  And it is `1`, so it is treated as true.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I wrongly simplified the query. The subquery is actually not a scalar subquery, like this: `(select max(B.created_datetime) where B.deleted is not null group by B.foo)` And this worked too. can you explain this too? I'll edit my question accordingly. But I still learned something new nonetheless from you.

Comment: If it's not a scalar subquery, it's not valid to use in a scalar context.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's what we thought too. Can you pinpoint the mistake that we made if there is any? I updated my question.

Comment: The query *is* scalar, because it's not selecting from several rows, but from the one B row the query is currently looking at. `B.deleted is not null` is either true or not for the one value in question, so you are either selecting one row or none. `max(B.created_datetime)` is just `B.created_datetime` for that one row. `group by B.foo` does nothing; one row remains one row, zero rows remain zero rows. That whole subquery either returns `B.created_datetime` or null, which the DBMS converts into a number in order to interpret it as a boolean, just as Gordon has already explained.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.seq = B.seq
WHERE (select max(B.data) where B.data is not null group by B.seq);
```

That can't be your real query. It is not valid SQL. This is what I get when I test it:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where B.data is not null group by B.seq)' at line 4

No doubt because it's not legal syntax to use a `where` clause or any clause that follows it if you don't have a `from` clause to define a table reference.

---

The test I did above was in MySQL 5.6, and I confirmed it returns the same error when I run the query in MySQL Workbench.

However, MySQL 8.0 supports new syntax. You *can* use `WHERE` and other clauses without a `FROM` clause. I didn't realize that before.

I apologize for being condescending, accusing you of not testing for errors.

Here's a demo:

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.17    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 42;
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 42 where true;
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
| 42 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 42 where false;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

MySQL always supported selecting a single row by specifying a set of fixed expressions in the select-list. Now with the new syntax, you can make that single row stay or be filtered out, depending on whether the `WHERE` clause is true or not.

In your query, the subquery is evaluated for each row of the outer query, so columns `B.data` and `B.seq` in the subquery have a single value each time the subquery runs. Just as if you had done a constant expression. The `GROUP BY` is irrelevant, since there's only one value for `B.seq` anyway.

Gordon Linoff is correct that the `WHERE` clause of the outer query will be either false if `max(B.data)` is 0 or else true if it's non-zero. If the subquery's `WHERE` clause is false, then the subquery will return no rows, which acts the same as if it had returned false.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.seq = B.seq WHERE (select true where true);
+-----+------+------+
| seq | seq  | data |
+-----+------+------+
|   1 |    1 | data |
+-----+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.seq = B.seq WHERE (select true where false);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Or if `max(b.data)` returns a value that is interpreted as a zero/false, it also makes the subquery evaluate to false, so the outer query returns no rows.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.seq = B.seq WHERE (select 0 where true);
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.seq = B.seq WHERE (select 'abc' where true);
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'abc' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That's weird... The example query and the table is working now. I added a screenshot to my question.